# Is there a way to get the value of a cell in google sheets and use it as a row in another formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AWCCE.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Aty0.png)

=average('Data Sheet'!H(C2):H(C3))

I want to get the average of a range of data from one sheet and put it into another sheet. I want to make it so that I can adjust the timeline. So I matched the dates and then got the row number. Now I want to use the column header that I know I want 'H' and put that together with the row number that is a variable that I store in C2 and C3 in the database sheet.

I tried to use several formulas I thought that I could just put parenthesis around the cell I wanted to get the value and it would figure out that I just wanted the number. I am new with sheets so it probably is an easy fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=average(indirect("'Data Sheet'!H"&C2&":H"&C3))
```

***OR*** this if you wish to disregard the helper cells (`C2`, `C3`) and directly go with dates in `B2`,`B3`

```js
=averageifs('Data Sheet'!H:H,'Data Sheet'!A:A,">="&B2,'Data Sheet'!A:A,"<="&B3)
```